# Stored Procedure: Cursor is bad?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I read somewhere that 99% of time you don't need to use a cursor.

But I can't think of any other way beside using a cursor in this following situation.

```
Select t.flag
From Dual t;
```

Let's say this return 4 rows of either `'Y'` or `'N'`. I want the procedure to trigger something if it finds `'Y'`. I usually declare a cursor and loop until `%NOTFOUND`. Please tell me if there is a better way.

Also, if you have any idea, when is the best time to use a cursor?

**EDIT**: Instead of inserting the flags, what if I want to do *"If `'Y'` then trigger something"*?

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479680/ms-sql-server-when-is-a-cursor-good/1479751#1479751

Comment: Add a `where t.flag = 'Y'` to your query? ... `INSERT INTO tbl_flag (<column list>) VALUES (<values>) WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Dual t where t.flag = 'Y') > 1`

Comment: MySQL, T-SQL and `dual`/`%NOTFOUND` (implying Oracle)?

Comment: Yes, it's Oracle. Sorry about that...
As I have edited, I try to trigger if Select query has 'Y'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case definitely falls into the 99%.

You can easily do the conditional insert using `insert into ... select...`. It's just a matter or making a `select` that returns the result that you want to insert.

If you want to insert one record for each `'Y'` then use a query with `where flag = 'Y'`. If you only want to insert a single record depending on whether there are at least one `'Y'`, then you can add `distinct` to the query.

A cursor is useful when you make something more complicated. I for example use a cursor when need to insert or update records in one table, and also for each record insert or update one or more records into several other tables.

Comment: How about trigger something? If it finds 'Y', put some created values or do something?

Comment: @sayhaha: Then you can use `if exists(select * from Dual where Flag = 'Y')`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_FLAG (col)
SELECT ID FROM Dual where flag = 'Y'
```

You will usually see a performance gain when using set based instead of procedural operations because most modern DBMS are setup to perform set based operations.  You can read more [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34142/Understanding-Set-based-and-Procedural-approaches).

Comment: How about trigger something? If it finds 'Y', put some created values or do something?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but a trigger is not what you need in this situation.

Comment: :p sorry So let's say If I run select * from dual; It returns 4 rows of {'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y'} then since system found 'Y' I want to query a value from TABLE1 and put it into TABLE2.

Answer (score 1):

well the example doesnt quite make sense..

but you can always write an `insert as select` statement instead of what i think you are describing

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are best to use when an column value form one table will be used repeatedly in multiple queries on different tables.

Suppose the values of id_test column are fetched from MY_TEST_TBL using a cursor CUR_TEST. Now this id_test column is a foreign key in MY_TEST_TBL. If we want to use id_test to insert or update any rows in table A_TBL,B_TBL and C_TBL, then in this case it's best to use cursors instead of using complex queries.

Hope this might help to understand the purpose of cursors