# iterate through select results

Tags: sql-server

I would like to make a list in SQLServer out of a select statement , and then use the result of this select statement to make sets of select, for example, if I have 3 values which returns from my first select, I'd like to run a While loop which will run 3 times and select values on each of the interation.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

I have a select statement:

```
Select ID
From T_1
Where T_1.somefield=1
```

The returned statement should be:

```
|1|
|2|
|4|
```

while 3 isn't displayed due to my Where condition.

I'd like to iterate through my results doing this

```
set @myCount=select count(id) from -my result-
set @indexFlag=0;

while (@indexFlag<@myCount)
Begin


Select *
From T_2
Where T_2.field=...(1 - 1st loop, 2- 2nd loop, 4- 3rd loop)


@indexFlag=@indexFlag+1
```

End

I'm not sure how to implement it, does SQLSERVER support some kind of list ?
Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Why can't you just do this using pure SQL?  Seems to me you could just select * from T_2 where T_2.field in (select * from T_1 ...) group by T1.ID

Comment: Application Manager requirements.. and I'd like to study more about SQLSERVER :)

Comment: You probably need cursors when, but if you want know more about SQLServer you shouldn't use cursors.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479680/ms-sql-server-when-is-a-cursor-good?rq=1

Comment: Learn how database work.  RDBMS is a set based operation.  You don't loop.  Learn how to use `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using joins for this.

```
select t_2.* from t_1 left join t_2 
on t_1.ID = t_2.ID
where t_1.some_field = 1
```

This will return all the rows required in one table itself. Then handle this table in your code to filter required rows.

Comment: I know I could use it , but my needs require to deal with each record seperately