# Is there any performance impact using cursors in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I need more information about the cursors.
Is there any performance impact using cursors in stored procedure?

Comment: Cursors are in general, always slower than processing via set logic.  If they can be avoided they should be for performance.  However, at times row-by-row processing simply can't be avoided, in which cases, cursors are the way to go vs pulling data back to a server, manipulating it and then updating.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287445/why-do-people-hate-sql-cursors-so-much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cursors are one of the worst things you can do for performance. They run row by row instead of impacting the whole set of data. No one except an experienced dba should ever consider writing one.

http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Comment: There are times and places to use them though once you have the experience to know how much impact they have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479680/ms-sql-server-when-is-a-cursor-good/1479751#1479751

Comment: I agree with HLGEM but read @xQbert comment. If its unavoidable give a look at the "fast_forward" option at declaring cursors