# Receive several values in one variable sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, variables, stored-procedures

I want to receive multiple data and store it in a variable in SQL Server, but stored procedures and functions don't allow to set table type to a variable, is there any other way to do that?

I need it because I want to make a method to send data from *Java*, but I don't know how to send several data to a single variable when using a function or a stored procedure, if there's any way to do that I'll be thankful if you let me know.

Comment: Maybe this will help you started about cursor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479680/ms-sql-server-when-is-a-cursor-good

Comment: @Charlesliam How could CURSOR help me in this case?

Comment: One way might be setting up a temp table, populating it with data from your code and using this temp table in your stored procedure.

Comment: @Szymon I thought about it, but how will i send the data from Java if it's a temp table?

Comment: I'm not completely sure about details in Java but I'm sure you can send queries like `create table #name...`, `insert into #name values...`

Comment: @NonExistent, `Cursor` will act as your temp_table in your procedure before you throw them into a variable where this variable can be your procedure output.

Comment: Yeah, but i mean, if i create a temp table how would insert data into it if i'll have be sending several querys from Java to SQL Server?, i want to avoid that, what i want is to send something like an array or a list of the data of each value that i'll insert into a table.

Comment: @NonExistent You should be able to send all queries in one go, separating them by `;`.

Comment: This is probably not the best idea but you could go oldschool with concatenate (stuff) and split (substring)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to, one way around the problem of passing a table-like data structure to a stored procedure/function is using a temp table:

1. Create a temp table (e.g. `#yourname`) from your code and insert records to it. You can do that using `create table` and `insert into`, sending all the data in one batch if needed, e.g.

   `create table #yourname (col1 int); insert into #yourname values (1); insert into #yourname values(2);`
2. Use the table with the populated data in your stored procedure.

Comment: Can u please give an example of what you give as answer, actually that's what we were discussing in the comments, thanks

Comment: @NonExistent Added an example.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, do you know any other way to send many data to sql server in a single variable?

Comment: I'm not so certain from Java. In .NET, you can craete a table variable parameter for stored proc and pass a DataTable from the code.