# How to use a While Loop in where clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table like the following with entries in the EntryTime column up to today.

**Table1**

```
PersonID|StartTime|EndTime|EntryTime
1       |10:00    |12:00  |2014-01-01
1       |10:00    |12:00  |2014-01-02
1       |10:00    |12:00  |2015-01-03
...
```

and a Contract Table:

**Table2**

```
PersonID|ContractID| ContractStart| ContractType|Hours
1       |1         |2014-01-01    |Student      |8
1       |2         |2015-01-01    |Trainee      |40
1       |3         |2015-03-01    |Student      |20
1       |4         |2015-05-01    |Student      |12
```

Now I want to sum the time `(datediff(minute, StartTime, Endtime))` for the current `contractType` using the result table mentioned below. The `contracttype` must be contiguous starting with the last one. So in this example all entries for the contract 3+4 are relevant.

My idea was to use a `loop` to select the relevant contracts.

```
WHILE (Select ContractType from Table2) = 'Student'
Begin
Select ContractStart from Table2
Order By ContractStart
End
```

Unfortunatley the loop is not working yet and if I do not know how to implement it into the where clause.

**The result** table I am trying to get is a `subset` of `Table1` with all entries starting at the 2015-03-01

Comment: Don't use loop for this. Prepare better http://www.sqlfiddle.com and you may get set based solution. Share also desired output for sample data.

Comment: Not related to your question, but is it possible for your records in table1 to span more than one calendar day?

Comment: No, it is not possible. E.g. if you work over night, you have to do two entries. That is as soon as I have the right date from table2 I can filter the table one quite easily.

Comment: Can you please post an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to know what do you want without an example but it's a try. Also make a lot of guesses about your types.

Note: [Avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479680/ms-sql-server-when-is-a-cursor-good) **while loops** and **cursors**, stick with set logic =)

```
declare @Table1 as table
(
    PersonID int
    ,StartTime datetime
    ,EndTime datetime
    ,EntryTime date
)

insert into @Table1
values
 (1       ,'10:00', '12:00', '2014-01-01')
,(1       ,'10:00', '12:00', '2014-01-02')
,(1       ,'10:00', '12:00', '2015-01-03')
,(2       ,'10:00', '12:00', '2015-01-03')
,(2       ,'10:00', '12:00', '2015-01-04')
,(3       ,'10:00', '12:00', '2015-01-03')
,(3       ,'10:00', '12:00', '2015-01-05')


declare @Table2 as table
(
    PersonID int
    ,ContractID int
    ,ContractStart date
    ,ContractType varchar(10)
    ,[Hours] float
)
insert into @Table2
values
 (1       ,1         ,'2014-01-01',    'Student',      8)
,(1       ,2         ,'2015-01-01',    'Trainee',      40)
,(1       ,3         ,'2015-03-01',    'Student',      20)
,(1       ,4         ,'2015-05-01',    'Student',      12)
,(2       ,1         ,'2014-01-01',    'Student',      8)
,(2       ,2         ,'2015-01-01',    'Trainee',      40)
,(2       ,3         ,'2015-03-01',    'Student',      20)
,(2       ,4         ,'2015-05-01',    'Student',      12)
,(3       ,1         ,'2014-01-01',    'Student',      8)
,(3       ,2         ,'2015-01-01',    'Trainee',      40)
,(3       ,3         ,'2015-03-01',    'Student',      20)
,(3       ,4         ,'2015-05-01',    'Student',      12)

--Current contrat (for PersonId = 1)
declare @CurrentType varchar(10) =
(select top 1 ContractType from @Table2 where PersonID = 1 order by ContractStart desc)

--Last different type start (for PersonId = 1)
declare @LastDiff date = 
(select top 1 ContractStart from @Table2 where PersonID = 1 and @CurrentType != ContractType order by ContractStart desc)

--Current type span (for PersonId = 1)
select datediff(minute, min(StartTime + cast(EntryTime as datetime)), max(EndTime + cast(EntryTime as datetime))) as [PesonId = 1 TimeSpan]
from @Table1
where PersonID = 1
and EntryTime > @LastDiff


-- Puting everything togheter
select t1.PersonId, datediff(minute, min(t1.StartTime + cast(t1.EntryTime as datetime)), max(t1.EndTime + cast(t1.EntryTime as datetime))) as TimeSpan
from @Table1 t1
where t1.EntryTime >
 (
    select top 1 t2.ContractStart
    from @Table2 t2
    where t2.PersonID = t1.PersonID
    and t2.ContractType != 
    (
       select top 1 t2b.ContractType from @Table2 t2b where t2b.PersonID = t2.PersonID order by t2b.ContractStart desc
    )
    order by t2.ContractStart desc
 )
group by t1.PersonId
```

The snippet is self explanatory and gives me:

```
PersonId TimeSpan
-------- --------
       1    120
       2    1560
       3    3000
```

Note I added a few data in order to make a better test example

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select Table1.PersonID, ContractID, datediff(minute, StartTime, Endtime) diff
    from Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 on Table2.PersonID = Table1.PersonID
    WHERE ContractType LIKE 'Student'
    GROUP BY Table1.PersonID, ContractID
```